# ElectronJS + React : EGL Driver message (Error) eglCreateContext: Requested GLES version (3.0) is greater than max supported (2, 0)

Tags: reactjs, electron

When I implement React on Electron Application, the Application works properly, but I get this message in the console frequently:

[11664:0410/082813.629:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglCreateContext: Requested GLES version (3.0) is greater than max supported (2, 0)

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it looks like because of some known bugs with the graphics driver you are using, Direct Composition has been disabled, meaning we need to use software rendering. Using software rendering comes with limitations in WebGL.

If you want to, you can try the following additional browser args:
`--ignore-gpu-blocklist`, `--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds`

Of course, I don't recommend this approach for a production app, as it will ignore changes and limitations due to graphics driver bugs and workarounds.